# what is meant of "sb.append(new StringBuffer(tx.nextToken()).reverse() +" ")"

Tags: java, string, stringtokenizer

What is meant by this line?

```
sb.append(new StringBuffer(tx.nextToken()).reverse() +" ")
```

can anyone explain about it in detail?

Answer (score 0):

`new StringBuffer(tx.nextToken()).reverse()` constructs a new StringBuffer, initialized by `tx.nextToken()` and then reverses the content of the buffer.

Therefore `sb.append(new StringBuffer(tx.nextToken()).reverse() +" ")` appends the reversed value of `tx.nextToken()` in addition to a space to `sb`.

Comment: This code should never appear in real life, I guess this was an exercise?